# Parallelize program to count integral using OpenMP C++

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm trying to count integral

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

double my_exp(double x) {
  double res = 1., term = 1.;
  for(int n=1; n<=1000; n++) {
    term *= x / n;
    res += term;
  }
  return res;
}

double f(double x) {
  return x*my_exp(x);
}


int main() {
  double a=0., b=1., result = 0.;
  int nsteps = 1000000;
  double h = (b - a)/nsteps;


  for(int i=1; i<nsteps; i++) result += f(a + i*h);
  result = (result + .5*(f(a) + f(b)))*h;

  cout.precision(15);
  cout << "Result: " << result << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This program count integral and return result `Result: 1.00000000000035`
. But time of execute is much.
I should parallel my program, I think I should add `#pragma omp parallel for` but it doesn't work

Comment: I'm suggesting you're using g++. Have you compiled it with `-fopenmp`?

Comment: Yes, I use g++ . I try `-fopenmp`, but it doesn't chenge the time of executing program. I should change my code, but I have never worked with `openmp`

Answer (score 1):

change your main function

```
#pragma omp parallel 
  {
  double localresult = 0.0;
#pragma omp for
  for(int i=1; i<nsteps; i++) 
      localresult +=  f(a + i*h);
#pragma omp critical
  {
      result += localresult;
  }
  }

  result = (result + .5*(f(a) + f(b)))*h;
```

edit: the much simpler solution along the lines of muXXmit2X would be

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result)
for(int i=1; i<nsteps; i++) result += f(a + i*h);

result = (result + .5*(f(a) + f(b)))*h;
```

Comment: Declaring `reduction(+: result)` would be simpler than using a local variable for the reduction, plus adding an extra step with `critical`

Comment: True. Bad style. I suggested it in a comment in a previous post that appears to be deleted now ... well, posting it anyway....

Comment: I think that it's uncorrect, because after that time of executing program must be much less. But it's 9 second like in my code

Comment: Nope. You are doing something wrong. Currently on windows, I get 6158.88 ms for your native code, 1725.02 ms for the reduction variant and 1788.51 for the local-variable variant. Amount of processes is set to 4. Please check your code again, and make sure your OMP_NUM_THREADS variable is set as well.